# Is it possible to map a prefixed list of env values into a map with Viper?

Tags: go, viper-go

I have a dotenv file in the current format

```
KEY_PATH=/keys
LOG_LEVEL=WARNING
DB_CUSTOMER1=dbone
DB_CUSTOMER2=dbtwo
```

I also have a struct in the form of

```golang
type MyConfiguration struct {
    KeyPath           string            `mapstructure:"KEY_PATH"`
    CustomerDB map[string]string `<???>`
    LogLevel          string            `mapstructure:"LOG_LEVEL"`
}
```

I'm looking and failing to find a way where I could map config keys taken as `DB_CUSTOMER1=val` to a map in the form of `"CUSTOMER1": "val"` either manually (eg: ask Viper for all keys with prefix DB_ and then set them myself) or automatically (but it seems Viper doesn't have a way to extract key/values this way).

I would appreciate any pointers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[spf13/viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper) predominantly uses [mapstructure](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure?tab=doc) package to convert between one native Go type to another i.e. when un-marshaling. You need to define an annotation that would cause any unused values to this map. There is an option to collect such [reminder values](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure#hdr-Remainder_Values). You need to modify the map to take an interface as

```golang
CustomerDB  map[string]interface{} `mapstructure:",remain"`
```

which would collect all your `DB_*` field values to the map as interface types, which you can type assert to get the required string value.

Comment: doesn't work quite like I need it to, unfortunately, but it's still a lot closer. Thanks